# How to insert list of data to single column row in Azure SQL/SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have tables like this:

```
Select CustomerName, CustomerSales, SalesDate 
From Customer
Select Month, WeeklyMessage 
From WeeklyReport
```

I would like to insert list of `CustomerName` and `Sales` to single row of `WeeklyMessage` like:

```
Tesla 1200 000\n
Toyota 500 000\n
```

I would next use this row for monthly notification.

Is this possible? What is Insert query that is able to store list to single row?

Comment: Are you, perhaps, after string aggregation? It is unclear, if I am honest.

Comment: Why do you need to redundantly store formatted data for a one-time notification? Generate the content, send the notification, if you have to do it again, do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store it as a json.

This query results a json formatted string:

```
select CustomerName, CustomerSales from Customer for json auto
```

That could be used to store the values into your WeeklyReport table.
You can query json and get its values as explained in this MS doc [JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=azuresqldb-current).

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you want to insert into the same colum the 2 values (name and number), i think you can do it simple if you do a relation with CustomerName and Sales.

> create table WeeklyMessage (
> name varchar(30),
> number integer,
> FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES CustomerName(name),
> FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Sales(number),
> PRIMARY KEY (name,number)
> );

and then insert it:

insert into WeeklyMessage values (Tesla, 1200 000);